# What happens under the hood in case of MQTT and MQTT over websocket?

Tags: http, websocket, mqtt

For each request both HTTP and web sockets make a 3 way handshake followed by the request/response and termination (persistent connection).

Similar to above, we have MQTT and MQTT over websocket, both are based on pub/sub model. MQTT is ideal on IoT hardware since certificate and key can be securely stored on the hardware device. Where as MQTT over websocket is ideal for mobile/web apps.

**What happens under the hood in the case of MQTT and MQTT over websocket in terms of handshake/data exchange/TCP/UDP?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference at all between MQTT and MQTT over Websockets.

There is just an extra part at the transport layer with MQTT over Websockets. So once the Websocket connection is setup the actual bytes that flow over the connection are exactly the same for native MQTT and MQTT over Websockets.

So you get the HTTP GET, UPGRADE flow and then it's straight in with the MQTT Connect packet as laid out in the [MQTT Spec](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html)

Comment: Can you add some more information like - handshake - http has 3 way handshake for each request. What about MQTT? I am trying to understand what happens under the hood in the case of MQTT and MQTT over websocket in terms of handshake/data exchange compared to HTTP?

Comment: There is no handshake, MQTT has a single persistent connection that is held open for the entire lifetime of the client.